# Фигурные скобки внутри определения структуры

Tags: c++, структуры, конструктор

```
struct Tree {
    Tree *left, *right;
    char Info;
    Tree(char info) { // <- поясните пожалуйста вот это момент в коде
        Info = info;  // <- и этот
    }
} *root = NULL;
```

Это создание внутри структуры еще одной, но в чем может быть необходимость этого в данном случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда код отформатирован, его легче читать.

```
struct Tree 
{
    Tree *left, *right;
    char Info;

    Tree(char info) 
    { 
        Info = info; <- и этот
    }
} *root = NULL;
```

Эту конструкцию можно разбить на две части.

```
struct Tree 
{
    Tree *left, *right;
    char Info;

    Tree(char info) 
    { 
        Info = info; <- и этот
    }
};

Tree *root = NULL;
```

То есть объявляется структура с именем `Tree`. Эта структура включает в себя явно определенный конструктор с параметром

```
Tree(char info) 
{ 
    Info = info; <- и этот
}
```

который вызывается при создании объектов.

А также здесь, как говорится, "в одном флаконе", определяется указатель на эту структуру, который изначально инициализируется null указателем

```
Tree *root = NULL;
```

Если требуется в динамической памяти создать объект этой структуры, то можно записать

```
root = new Tree( 'A' );
```

В этом случае выделится память под объект и будет вызван конструктор структуры

```
Tree(char info) 
{ 
    Info = info; <- и этот
}
```

который инициализирует поле структуры `Info` символом `'A'`.

Так как члены структуры в отличии от членов класса по умолчанию являются открытыми, то после создания объекта структуры вы можете изменять значения его полей. Например,

```
root = new Tree( 'A' );

root->Info = 'B';
```

Comment: Воот! Стало яснее, спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

*Это* называется конструктором. Если более точно, то конструкором с параметром. Конструкторы нужны для создания объекта класса.

```
Tree tr('h');
std::cout << tr.Info << std::endl;
```

Вывод:

> h

Возможно, вам следует прочитать какую-нибудь книгу по программрованию на С++.

Comment: но в чем может быть необходимость этого в данном случае?

Comment: Не очень понятно, как можно судить о необходимости чего бы то ни было без примера использования.

Comment: Как раз сейчас и читаю книгу, но этот момент был неясен. Мне скорее важно понять, как он работает - то есть он передает значение в элемент структуры Info, но почему нельзя просто использовать *tree->Info ? Какая необходимость в использовании этого конструктора?

Comment: Ваш вопрос уже выходит за рамки первоначального. Откройте книгу или google и посмотрите там информацию о конструкторах.